# How do I check my email is available in database or not

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I wrote one model that is having email field. I added some emails to it by admin. What I need is when I type any email that should check with my database email if exist it should show email is already there:

**models.py** #in my database already some data is there

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**forms.py**

```
class FriendForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Friend
        fields = ['email']
```

**views.py**

```
def check(request):
    form = FriendForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = Friend.objects.filter(**form.cleaned_data)
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "one.html", context)
```

I imported every thing. When I am trying this code it is directly rendering to one.html. What I need is it should check if email is there in database then only it should render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Friend(models.Model):
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,unique=True,error_messages={'error':'The Email already exists'})
```

you can change your model to this.

```
if form.is_valid():
    form = Friend.objects.filter(**form.cleaned_data)
else:
    redirect('to_some_page')
```

Comment: if i want to redirect to other html page

Comment: sorry, try it now